# JQuery check and remove slash from the end of URL read

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

In a jQuery script I have the line of code which gets the string of current URL:

```
var target = $(this).attr('href');
```

Could the code in this script check if there is a slash at the end of the URL string. If it is present then remove it? What is the way to do it, you could recommend?

Comment: Just so we're clear: "/" is a *slash*, and "\" is a *backslash*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
 target = target.replace(/\/$/, '');
```

Now if you need to worry about the presence of a query string:

```
 <a href='http://foo.bar.com/something/?param=xyz'>hi</a>
```

then things get a little more tricky. Parsing a URL with a regex is probably possible, but it's pretty messy. If you can get away with it, narrow down the possibilities of what your URLs can look like so that you don't have to use some big huge "official" pattern.

Comment: Even better, continue the jquery chain style and do `var target = $(this).attr('href').replace(/\/$/,'');`

Comment: @Martin Jespersen yes in actual code that's (probably) what I'd do but I wanted the example to be really clear in terms of the "good" part.

Comment: how can I remove the slash from the beggining of a text?

Answer (score 4):

This should be safe for URLs with query strings as well, AND it doesn't use a regex....

```
var urlEnd = target.indexOf("?");
if(urlEnd == -1){
    urlEnd = target.length;
}

// Don't bother doing anything if the URL is empty
if (urlEnd > 0){
    if (target[urlEnd - 1] == "/"){
        $(this).attr('href', target.substr(0, urlEnd-1) + target.substr(urlEnd));
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean a slash, one possible solution would be:

```
var l = target.length - 1;
if(target.lastIndexOf('/') === l) {
    target = target.substring(0, l);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a regex like:

target.replace(//+((\?|#).*)?$/, '$1');

Which should preserve query strings or url fragments at the end of the URL.