# Return string without trailing slash

Tags: javascript, string, trailing-slash

I have two variables:

```
site1 = "www.somesite.com";  
site2 = "www.somesite.com/";
```

I want to do something like this

```
function someFunction(site)
{
    // If the var has a trailing slash (like site2), 
    // remove it and return the site without the trailing slash
    return no_trailing_slash_url;
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery check and remove slash from the end of URL read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740364/jquery-check-and-remove-slash-from-the-end-of-url-read)

Answer (score 627, accepted):

Try this:

```
function someFunction(site)     
{     
    return site.replace(/\/$/, "");
}
```

Comment: To handle cases with multiple trailing slashes, you can use:
`return site.replace(/\/+$/, "");`

Comment: "/".replace(/\/$/, "") will be "". "/" is a valid path and it shouldn't be stripped.

Comment: Be careful with `/\/+$/`, which is in a comment here that is upvoted 150 times at the time of this writing. It is subject to ReDoS. That doesn't matter in a lot of cases, but could be a big problem if you are using this (for example) in server-side Node.js code.

Comment: @Trott can you suggest some answer which isn't susceptible to that attack?

Comment: @Gourav `function removeAllTrailingSlashes(str) {let i = str.length; while (str[--i] === '/'); return str.slice(0, i+1);}`

Comment: @Trott ah thanks! I've been looking through lots of regex lately, seems like I started forgetting this basic stuff xD

Comment: This one will not work for `document.referrer` where you could have the protocol `https://stackoverflow.com/`

Comment: To ensure you're only removing a trailing slash prefixed with a word, you can use `site.replace(/(?<=\w)\/+/, '')`. This uses the positive lookbehind pattern `(?<=)` to ensure that the match is prefixed by a word `\w`. See this [RegEx](https://regexr.com/7e056).

Answer (score 103):

ES6 / ES2015 provides an API for asking whether a string ends with something, which enables writing a cleaner and more readable function.

```
const stripTrailingSlash = (str) => {
    return str.endsWith('/') ?
        str.slice(0, -1) :
        str;
};
```

Comment: best solution in 2019 

Comment: @PaulRad While using this soln, getting issue of str.slice(0, -1) branch not covered for this line on unit test. How to fix that?

Comment: @BijayRai that means your tests are missing a case where `str` ends with a `/` slash. You should have two assertions (or two tests), one with a slash and one without.

Answer (score 88):

```
function stripTrailingSlash(str) {
    if(str.substr(-1) === '/') {
        return str.substr(0, str.length - 1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Note: IE8 and older do not support negative substr offsets. Use `str.length - 1` instead if you need to support those ancient browsers.

Comment: Really like the use of term 'ancient' here.

Comment: function stripTrailingSlash(str) {
    if(str.startsWith("/")) {
        return str.substr(1, str.length - 1);
    }
    return str;
}

NOT FOR IE8...  who uses IE8 anyway ?

Answer (score 34):

I'd use a regular expression:

```
function someFunction(site)
{
// if site has an end slash (like: www.example.com/),
// then remove it and return the site without the end slash
return site.replace(/\/$/, '') // Match a forward slash / at the end of the string ($)
}
```

You'll want to make sure that the variable `site` is a string, though.

Comment: I totally agree, anytime you write regex, it should be wrapped in a function with a descriptive name or with comments.

Answer (score 29):

Based on @vdegenne 's answer... how to strip:

Single trailing slash:

`theString.replace(/\/$/, '');`

Single or consecutive trailing slashes:

`theString.replace(/\/+$/g, '');`

Single leading slash:

`theString.replace(/^\//, '');`

Single or consecutive leading slashes:

`theString.replace(/^\/+/g, '');`

Single leading and trailing slashes:

`theString.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '')`

Single or consecutive leading and trailing slashes:

`theString.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '')`

To handle both slashes and *back*slashes, replace instances of `\/` with `[\\/]`

Comment: Some of the solutions here, such as `/\/+$/g` are susceptible to ReDoS so care must be taken if using on server-side code, for example.

Answer (score 21):

I know the question is about trailing slashes but I found this post during my search for trimming slashes (both at the tail and head of a string literal), as people would need this solution I am posting one here :

```
'///I am free///'.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, ''); // returns 'I am free'
```

---

**UPDATE**:

as *@Stephen R* mentioned in the comments, if you want to remove both slashes and backslashes both at the tail and the head of a string literal, you would write :

```
'\/\\/\/I am free\\///\\\\'.replace(/^[\\/]+|[\\/]+$/g, '') // returns 'I am free'
```

Comment: This is the real answer!

Comment: If you want to trim both slashes and backslashes: `.replace(/^[\\/]+|[\\/]+$/g, '')`

Comment: The solutions in this answer are subject to ReDoS attacks, so you may wish to avoid them if they are being used in server-side code (using Node.js or deno, for example). Depending on where the path is coming from, you may want to use caution with browser code too.

Answer (score 12):

This snippet is more accurate:

```
str.replace(/^(.+?)\/*?$/, "$1");
```

1. It not strips `/` strings, as it's a valid url.
2. It strips strings with multiple trailing slashes.

Comment: While this may be a valid approach to removing multiple slashes, that's not the request of the OP.

Comment: @JonL. Many people browse stack overflow to find answer. I find this answer helpful than the accepted answer.

Comment: I think this is more simpler -> `(.+?)\/+$`. No need to use `^` at first because `.` will search from the start anyway, No need to use `*?` at before `$` because it will be return original string when regex pattern not matched.

Comment: This answer is highly susceptible to ReDos and should probably be avoided in server-side code and other contexts where ReDoS attacks are a concern.

Answer (score 4):

```
function stripTrailingSlash(text) {
    return text
        .split('/')
        .filter(Boolean)
        .join('/');
}
```

another solution.

Comment: this won't work if you have string = "/"

Comment: This wont work for URLs - you will have http:// changed to http:/

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I know of is this:

```
function stripTrailingSlash(str){
   if(str.charAt(str.length-1) == "/"){ str = str.substr(0, str.length - 1);}
   return str
}
```

Updates ES2015 version.

```
const stripTrailingSlash = str=>str.charAt(str.length-1)=="/"?str.substr(0,str.length-1):str;
```

This will then check for a / on the end and if it's there, remove it. If it's not, it will return your string as it was.

Fixed the calculation for zero-based index on the string.

**EDIT:**
As there was a comment to one response there are now more doing the same thing do not use sub string for a comparison, you're creating a whole new string in memory (at the low level) when you can use `charAt` to get a single char a lot less memory to do your comparison, Javascript is still JIT and can't do the optimisations to the level any lang going though a compiler can, it won't fix this for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here a small url example.

```
var currentUrl = location.href;

if(currentUrl.substr(-1) == '/') {
    currentUrl = currentUrl.substr(0, currentUrl.length - 1);
}
```

log the new url

```
console.log(currentUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const url = new URL("https://some.site/some/path/?somekey=somevalue");
url.pathname.endsWith('/') && (url.pathname = url.pathname.slice(0, -1));
url.toString() // 'https://some.site/some/path?qk=213&hded=444';
```

Answer (score -6):

In case you are working with URLs then you can use the built-in URL class

```
const url = new URL('https://foo.bar/');
console.log(url.toString()); // https://foo.bar
```

Comment: url.toString will not remove the slash

Comment: You should test your code before answering. It results in `https://foo.bar/`.

Answer (score -13):

```
function someFunction(site) {
  if (site.indexOf('/') > 0)
    return site.substring(0, site.indexOf('/'));
  return site;
}
```

Comment: `subtring`? Besides that, it removes the first slash and everything after it.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Really? You can't tell that I meant `substring`? Also yes, I meant to remove the first slash and everything after it since it does fill the bill for the question and example data posted.

Comment: Well his comment says he wants to remove the trailing slash

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Which, according to his examples, my code does.

Comment: Just a not why not to use this at any point if the urls change to be "fully-qualified" have http:// this wont work and any links with / in the middle wont work *for googlers*